# How do I generate a script of all database objects in Toad for MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-schema, toad, sql-scripts

In the freeware version of [Toad for MySQL](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113858/quickly-generate-ascii-text-sql-scripts-based-off-of-sql-2008-database) (latest version), I can generate a script of all tables in my database in one file.  However, for stored procedures and functions, Toad generates a separate script/file for each one.

**Ideally, I'd like a simple step to generate a script for all objects in my database (tables, views, procedures, functions, triggers) *to a single file*.**

Is that possible in Toad for MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I think I have found a definitive answer.  This operation cannot be done in Toad for MySQL.  What do all of you do?!**

- [SQL Export suggestions on Toad for MySQL forums](http://www.toadformysql.com/thread.jspa?messageID=110108)

> We have been asking for this feature for many years and it has been never implemented. We hope to have that this year. We'll see.

-Ernest

> I don't know why so few people are asking for those "Scripts" enhancement features. I comes from the Microsoft SQL sides, with Toad, I can't select any objects(views, procedures ) then generate DDL and rerun it in Production system. The stored procedures  script generated from Toad can't even run in Production unless "Delimiter" is added.

-Lawrence

*Note: I have found a suitable option for now using HeidiSQL (see other answer), but HeidiSQL is not as robust as Toad for MySQL, and I would prefer not to mix IDEs.*

Answer (score 12):

I am happy to report that [**HeidiSQL**](http://www.heidisql.com/) does exactly what I need it to do.  *This feature alone is worth having the 3 MB .exe on your system:*

[image]

As a bonus, it's lightweight and fast.  It can't do everything Toad for MySQL does, but for most tasks, I will default to Heidi instead of `SUPER SLOW` Toad!

**If someone can still answer my question about how to do this operation in Toad for MySQL, I will change my accepted answer.**

*(and another option I have is using [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html))*

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still needing an answer for Toad...
Go to the Object Explorer -> select all the tables -> Right click and select 'Send To -> Editor As Script'

Comment: This solution also works for Procedures. Object Explorer -> select all the procedures -> Right click and select 'Send To -> Editor As Script'.

Answer (score 2):

What about `Database` -> `Export` -> `Generate schema script`. After that - spefify DDL file name and on `Object types` tab select needed types.

PS: oops, I've given a recipe for `Toad for Oracle`, but may be for mysql it is similar

Comment: Thanks zerkms, unfortunately it's not similar at all :(

Comment: thanks, I'm searching for Oracle exactly. May it will help others

Answer (score 1):

Go to tools -> Export --> Export wizard
[image: Click Next]

Click Next -> Add -> Databases

Select the databases you want to export

Click Next

Select the output format as SQL script

[image: Select other options as below]

Click Next -> Next -> Next -> export data

Your .sql scripts will exported to the file location

Comment: If you want to export the complete DB in a single file heidi is better.

Comment: Just does the data, not structure. Cannot do as one file.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround how to do it.
In Object Explorer select all tables then Generate SQL > Creation Script. You have to run it few times on fresh database if you have relations.
Unfortunately this can not be done for procedures.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using Tools > Compare function.
You compare database with empty one, than after Toad compared databases Press Synchronize, then you will see option to open script in an editor.